# Why can't I move files to my WD-drive from my mac?

Tags: imac

I bought a WD My Passport (Essential) 500GB a few days ago. I needed it to move my old files from my Pc to my new iMac. I connected it to my Pc and installed WD Smartware on it so it could be used and then moved over my files, no problem. Then I connected it to my iMac and I moved the files from the hard drive to the computer, but I can't erase any files from the hard drive when it's connected to my Mac, and I can't move any files from my mac to the hard drive. How do I fix this?

/Magnus

Comment: I suspect the external drive is using NTFS as it's filesystem? I'm not a Mac user, but I understand that Mac's will (by default?) only access NTFS filesystems in read-only mode. Hopefully someone can suggest a way around this for you.

Answer (score 3):

I use [NTFS-3G](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/24481/ntfs-3g)

From site:

> NTFS-3G for Mac OS X is a software project designed to bring NTFS read/write support to Mac OS X along with additional advanced features.